# Vector value missing when access from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, mutex

In my c++ application am using 2 threads,

Thread 1 adds the values into vector and Thread2 swap the vector and process it.

```
void Test::MoveToSlowMap(ProfiledInfo* pInfo)
{
            try
            {
                lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(VectMutex);
                swapBucket->push_back(pInfo);
                fileLogObj->WriteRequestLog("[INFO]","Data added into vector" ,0);
            }
            catch(...)
            {
                fileLogObj->WriteRequestLog("[ERROR]"," Exception in Movetoslowmap " ,0);
            }
}


void Test::GetClassObj(vector<ProfiledInfo*>* toSwaps)
{
        lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(VectMutex);
        fileLogObj->WriteAgentCommLog("[INFO]", "GetClassObj Before swap -  ", swapBucket->size());
        toSwaps->swap(*swapBucket);
}
```

movetoslowmap function called by Thread1 and printed the logs after push_back.
GetClassObj called from Thread2 every 10 sec to copy swapBucket vector to empty vector (toSwaps).

some time, "Data added into vector" values printed 1000 times, which means pushed 1000 values into vector.
But its not swapped all the values from thread2. I added size of vector from the logs "GetClassObj Before swap - ".
this sum of size will be < 1000 not always.

What i am missing here ? why the exact values not captured in thread 2? Is this issue coming from vector push_back or swap?

Comment: What you are missing here is a [mre], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. The shown code fails to meet its requirements, as such it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @samvarshavchik

Comment: As Sam says, we can't do much except wild guesses without a program that reproduces the problem.  If you want a wild guess: it could be that your logging functions are flushing messages from different threads such that some messages from before a swap only appear in the log after the swap.  I suggest you add the size() when you `push_back`, and see if the messages reach the maximum documented during the swap (even if later in the log file).  Do you know if it's actually functionally misbehaving - or are you just worried by not seeing what you expect in the log?